# VB.NET equivalent to C# var keyword

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, keyword, var

Is there a VB.NET equivalent to the C# `var` keyword?

I would like to use it to retrieve the result of a LINQ query.

Comment: IMHO: Although this is a duplicate question, the answers & comments below provide more detail about the use of `option infer` and `option strict`, than the previously asked question. I prefer **THIS** Q & A, to that original.

Answer (score 153):

[Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) must be **on** in order for this to function properly. If so, then omitting the type in VB.NET (Visual Basic 9) will implicitly type the variable.

This is *not* the same as "Option Strict Off" in previous versions of VB.NET, as the variable *is* strongly-typed; it's just done so implicitly (like the C# `var`) keyword.

```
Dim foo = "foo"
```

`foo` is declared as a `String`.

Comment: asked something and find the answer right away

Comment: Isn't Dim foo  equivalent to dynamic foo instead ?

Comment: @Quandary +Adam: IIRC, When "Option Infer" is OFF, the result is dynamic foo, for backward compatibility. Maybe "Option Strict" has to also be OFF for it to be dynamic, not sure. **EDIT** I just saw Konrad's answer. He explains the different combinations.

Answer (score 45):

You need `Option Infer On` and then just use the `Dim` keyword, thus:

```
Dim query = From x In y Where x.z = w Select x
```

Contrary to some of the other answers, you *do not* need `Option Strict On`.

If you're using the VS IDE you can just hover over the variable names, but to get the compile-time types of variables (`GetType(variableName)` does not compile - "Type '<variablename>' is not defined." - and `VarType(variable)` is actually just the VB version of `variable.GetType()` which returns the type of the instance stored in the variable at runtime) I used:

```
Function MyVarType(Of T)(ByRef Var As T) As Type
    Return GetType(T)
End Function
```

In detail:

- without `Dim`:

  `Explicit Off`, gives `Object`

  `Explicit On`, error "Name '' is not declared."
- with `Dim`:

  - `Infer On`, gives expected types
  - `Infer Off`:

    `Strict On`, error "Option Strict On requires all declarations to have an 'As' clasue."

    `Strict Off`, gives `Object`

As I mentioned in the comments, there are [other reasons](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10457) why `Option Strict On` allows Linq to perform more usefully. Specifically, you can't get `Into Max(Anon.SomeString)` to work with `Option Strict Off`, though there are a number of workarounds.

Comment: You can simply use `x.GetType()` in VB – I hadn’t tested my answer’s code, hence the mistake in my old answer. This actually yields the runtime type which can differ from what you get using `GetType(T)`, though. Finally, `Strict On` if course not required for this to work, but should be always on, anyway, and may prevent mistakes if the programmer has forgotten to specify `Infer On`.

Comment: I agree `Option Strict On` is good practice, but `x.GetType` doesn't provide the answer to the question asked here. I haven't tested it, but with `Infer Off` and `Strict Off` a simple `Dim query = From ...` example may work (although the guts of Linq queries may need some of the other effects of `Strict On` or `Infer On` to work correctly) and `query.GetType()` will return the anonymous type, not `Object`, which query will be declared to be.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I've altered my answer to reflect this adjustment. The wording of the MSDN docs is awkward and seems to imply that `Strict` is required, but they don't actually say that.

Comment: Mark, it might be worth mentioning, in your **without Dim** section, that `Strict On` also forces/implies `Explicit On`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329  So no one needs to worry about `Explicit`, if they are using `Strict On`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I would mention it, except the Microsoft support article is currently wrong: `Explicit On` is the default, but you can override it and still have `Strict On`. Then you can still have undeclared `Object` variables, but `Dim` statements must have an `As` clause (unless `Infer On` is also in effect). Sample code: http://ideone.com/rnC1Xk (ideone itself doesn't have a recent enough VB.NET compiler -- just using it as a public notepad)

Answer (score 18):

Simply use the conventional `Dim` keyword without a type.

Minimal working example:

```vb
Option Strict On ' Always a good idea
Option Infer On ' Required for type inference

Imports System

Module MainModule
    Sub Main()
        Dim i = 42
        Dim s = "Hello"
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i.GetType(), s.GetType())
        ' Prints System.Int32, System.String '
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Isn't this wrong? According to other answers, Only `Option Infer` is needed? (Option Strict solves a different issue.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Right. In a preview version of Visual Studio (don’t remember which one) you needed both, AFAIR.

Comment: The `.GetType` result would be the same if you had `Infer Off` and `Strict Off`, but the `i` and `s` would actually be `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

**Object** worked for me in this example

**C#**

```
JToken projects = client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, new { groupID = userGroupID });
foreach( var j in projects["data"].Children()) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}", j.Value<string>("name"));
}
```

**VB**

```
Dim projects As JToken = client.Search(ObjCode.PROJECT, New With { _
Key .groupID = userGroupID _
})

For Each j As Object In projects("data").Children()
       Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}", j.Value(Of String)("name"))
Next
```

Comment: The VB code is using late binding here. (You wouldn't have intellisense when you type `j.`.) This does _not_ correspond to the C# code.

Comment: So we are saying there is no direct equivalent in VB for the var keyword when using a loop variable in a for loop e.g. the j above?  This is the exact scenario I want var because I have a collection coming back from LINQ using an anonymous type so how do I get the elements?!

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Just use `For Each j In ...` the type will then be inferred.

Comment: -1 because the result is dynamic (late) binding. Therefore, this is not an answer to the poster's question. I recommend removing this answer (which will also remove the -1 charge).