# The equivalent for var keyword in Vb.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.NET equivalent to C# var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478552/vb-net-equivalent-to-c-sharp-var-keyword)

I'm doing C# And now I want to learn about VB.Net, and I want the equivalent for this:

```
var result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Dim` without a type designator.

```
Dim result = loginForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yes, the variable declared like this (in VB and C#) is not a variant or the like. Instead, the compiler infers the type from the initializing expression.

Comment: Must have Option Infer On as well