# How to convert Var from C# to VB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I found the following C# code which is useful for me:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page 
  { 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (Session["EID"] != null) 
        { 
            int EmpID = (int)Session["EID"]; 

            DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext(); 
            var empInfo = from emp in dc.EmployeeLogins 
                          where emp.EmployeeID == EmpID 
                          select new
                          { 
                                     emp.EmployeeLoginKey, 
                                     emp.EmployeeID, 
                                     emp.username, 
                                     emp.passwd 
                          }; 

           foreach (var v in empInfo) 
           { 
               lblID.Text = v.EmployeeID.ToString(); 
               lblLoginKey.Text = v.EmployeeLoginKey.ToString(); 
               lblPassword.Text = v.passwd.ToString(); 
               lblUserName.Text = v.username.ToString(); 

            } 
       } 
       else 
       { 
           Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I had used online converter converted to vb, when I compile the program, it returns an error for the following sentence:

```
For Each v As var In empInfo
```

how to convert var from c# to vb?

Comment: [VB.NET equivalent to C# var keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489467/745969)

Comment: Please format your code in future - it's very hard to read with no indentation.

Comment: what is "empInfo" in statement var empInfo = from emp in dc.EmployeeLogins

Comment: @SatpalSingh - `empInfo` will be the collection of the anonymous type resulting form the LINQ query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each v In empInfo
```

To get VB to infer variable types, just omit the `As` clause, e.g.

```
Dim a = b + c
```

**NOTE:** This will only work when `Option Infer` is `On`. When `Option Infer` is `Off`, then variables without type specifiers will default to `Object` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip type declaration: `For Each v In empInfo`.

You have to have `Option Infer On` set.

Formal [`For Each` statement syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is described on MSDN as following:

```
For Each element [ As datatype ] In group
    [ statements ]
    [ Continue For ]
    [ statements ]
    [ Exit For ]
    [ statements ]
Next [ element ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
For Each Dim item In empInfo
```

Comment: It's not gonna work. `Expression Expected` error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
foreach (Dim v in empInfo) 
                lblID.Text = v.EmployeeID.ToString()
                lblLoginKey.Text = v.EmployeeLoginKey.ToString()
                lblPassword.Text = v.passwd.ToString()
                lblUserName.Text = v.username.ToString()
 Next
```

Don't forget to add below lines at top of the page

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
```

Comment: You need to enable both `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` to make this work, otherwise the code either will not compile

Comment: 'either will not compile'... or?