# Does Visual Basic use stucture or name type equivalence, or both?

Tags: vb.net, types, equivalence

Just having a hard time understanding if Visual Basic uses structure or name type equivalence (or both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Basic is [*nominatively* ("by name") typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system) - and *not* [structurally typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

While VB.NET supports "late dispatch" or dynamic typing via ["Strict Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2890023/2246674), this is not related to the underlying (CLR) type system. In addition, ["Infer On"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489467/2246674) is also an orthogonal construct as the compiler still figures out the types "by name".

Basically: if a type *name* is required to achieve *static typing* (e.g. for "type equivalency"), then it is a *nominatively* typed language.

---

Even languages like Ruby/Python are nominatively typed. However, because they are also entirely dynamically typed and explicit type-checking is often eschewed, it is often considered that the types therein are "used structurally". That is, [if it quacks like a duck..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test)

An example of a language with structural typing *support* is Scala. Consider this small example where A and B are *independent* types (they do not share an interface or relevant super type) but they can be unified around their structure (aliased as T):

```scala
case class A { def hi = "A" }
case class B { def hi = "B" }

// structure declaration: aliased, but "nameless"
type T = { def hi: String }  
// both A and B can be "used as" the structure declared
def sayHi (it: T) = println(it.hi)

sayHi(A())
sayHi(B())
```

Comment: +1 for the wonderful explanation and examples in other languages. Well done! :-)